# Overlapping DIVs while keeing the back one controllable

Tags: html, css, vue.js, leaflet

I managed to overlap my right hand content above my leaflet map in the background by using `position` and `z-index`. But I want to keep the map in back still controllable.

Is there a way, if yes which one, to make the background of the overlapping `div` not only transparent but also non interactive?

https://jsfiddle.net/8kujbh3g/3/

Answer (score 1):

As so often [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839672/5811471) brought the answer.

Basically its

overlapping parent
`pointer-events: none;`

overlapping child
`pointer-events: auto;`

https://jsfiddle.net/8kujbh3g/4/

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve that is to let the left hand content overlap with right hand content. Instead of using, add margin to the left hand content. Check the code below.

```css
div.map {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
  margin-top: 16px;
}

div.controls {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.25);
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map">
    <a href='#'>My occupied link</a>
  </div>
  <div class="controls">
    <div class="main-controls">
      Here goes some more controls
    </div>
    <div class="actual-controls">
      <a href='#'>toolbox link</a><br />
      <a href='#'>toolbox link</a><br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you @Pranav_Rustagi - Please find my updated version in the OT. The background has to be fully accessible, apart from the controls in the front

Comment: @da-chiller It does not seem possible to do that, unless, you position every element which has to be accessible, individually. If you want to keep the background color, you can create a div and set its z-index to minimum of all. And clear rest of the backgrounds.

Comment: @Pranav_Rustagi look what SO found just next to your comment :)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4839672/5811471
Thanks again.